# Problem applying function via Pandas apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, statsmodels

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def test_diff(ts):
    stat_p, _, _, _, crit_p, _ = adfuller(ts)
    if stat_p < crit_p['5%']:
        return ts.diff()
    else:
        return ts


df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
        'p1': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200],
        'p2': [100, 750, 1300, 250, 1200],
        })
```

This works on single column so it seems this is a problem with the pandas part:

```
test_diff(df['p1'])
```

I want to group the DataFrame by the name column then apply the adfuller test to column's p1 and p2 for that group and then if necessary return the original or differenced time series depending on the test result.

So far I have tried:

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda df: test_diff(df['p1']))
```

But get error:

```
ValueError: sample size is too short to use selected regression component
```

I have also tried:

```
  df.groupby('name').apply(test_diff, ['p1'])
```

But get error:

```
TypeError: test_diff() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using Pandas [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) and [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from Python standard library's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module:

```py
results = [
    test_diff(df.loc[df["name"] == name, col])
    for name, col in product(df["name"].unique(), ("p1", "p2"))
]
```